# Storage accessible by Javascript and Php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, local-storage, storage

Is there any storage like cookies that is accessible by JavaScript and PHP, I would use cookies, but their maximum capacity is too low, and I cant figure how to access HTML5 Local Storage by PHP.

Comment: What is the original task you're solving? (asking because this question is a candidate for an XY-problem)

Comment: I have this web app https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41468627/index.html and I can use anything to save whats done (I want to use JS, beacause, then I can save after whatever is done) but I need to be able to load it without JS

Comment: Then you need to persist that data to the server via AJAX.

Comment: If your server needs to access it, then you need to store it on the server.

Comment: Cookies are not a storage that can be accessed by your server and the client at any time. Cookies are data that are sent to the server every time an HTTP request is sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cloud service like [DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com) and communicate with **[PHP](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/php)** and **[Javascript](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/sdks/js)**

Honestly I would go with the PouchDB *illusion* @meagar mentioned but it's subjective to your preference and what you're objective is (and what risks you are willing to take).

You can also do it quite easily yourself with `window.localStorage` in Javascript then syncing with AJAX to the PHP backend.

**[HTML5 localStorage lowdown](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)**

Answer (score 7):

No, there isn't.

You need to communicate back and forth between the browser and server via HTTP requests. There is no other way for them to share data. There are storage solutions like [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/) that provide the *illusion* of shared client/server storage, but they're simply doing the HTTP request part for you.

Your data storage should be server-side. Your browser "stores" data by sending that data to the server via an HTTP request, and later retrieves that data the same way. This is how every virtually every website you've ever visited stores any substantial amount of data.